# Get $form_state values from individual entity form fields

Tags: 8, forms

I have a weird use case. I created a custom form with some fields and I added some other fields from one entity form like this:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $entity_fields = array('entity_field_1', 'entity_field_2');
    // added other form fields here
    $entityForm = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($entity, 'default');
    foreach( $entity_fields as $key ) {
        $form[$key] = $entityForm[$key];
    }
    // etc
    return $form;
}
```

I need to get the exact entity field widget because these fields can be updated from the interface and I can't have them hard-coded.

Now, If I submit the form, the form state values for 'entity_field_1', 'entity_field_2' are empty. `$form_state->getValue('entity_field_1')` is returning an empty array. Other fields defined manually are returning the correct value when saving.

How do I get those entity field values? In drupal 7 I used field_attach_submit() to attach the form values to an entity.

Comment: Have you tried to use? $form_state->getValue('entity_field_1') instead of $form_state->get('entity_field_1')

Comment: Why do you ask?

Comment: Yeah, getValue() I used and it doesn't work. It was a typo in the question and I will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try `$form_state->getValues()['entity_field_1']` as `getValues()` will build an array of values with the field name as the key.